# Error i not defined in for loop using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one array 'barray' of size 'bsize' and another 'carray' of size 'csize'.
The `i` loop is for barray and `j` loop is for carray.

I get an error that i is not defined. I want the loops to go from 0 to bsize - 2 in steps of 3, and 0 to csize - 2 in single steps.

How should I relate the size and array to the for loop?

```
bsize = 960
csize = 960
barray = bytearray(fi.read())
carray= bytearray(f1.read())



for i in range (bsize-2,i+3):
    for j in range (csize-2,j+1):
```

Comment: So, what exactly do you want `i` to be in the first loop? 0 to `bsize - 2`? `bsize - 2` to something?

Comment: I want i to take the barray from 0 to bsize-2 and increment by 3 and j to take carray ffrom 0 to csize-2 and increment by 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 for i in range (0, bsize - 2, 3): #possibly bsize - 1?
    for j in range (csize - 2): # possibly csize - 1?
        #do your thing
```

That will loop through the first one incrementing `i` by 3 every time, and `j` by 1.

Look at this [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html) or these [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) to learn `range`, it's really useful!

I'm not sure if you want to go through bsize - 2 or just up to it. If through, use size - 1 to get size - 2.

The reason you're getting an error is that you haven't defined the `i` you're using in the step. As you can see, python's `range` isn't like a lot of other languages' `for` constructs. Once you get used to it, though, it's really flexible and easy to use.

Some examples using simple range:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 14, 3):
...    print i
... 
0
3
6
9
12

>>> for i in range(1, 5):
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
4

>>> for i in range(5):
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```